# Show a div after submitting a form and keep the information of the form

Tags: javascript, php

I need to show a div after receiving info from a form. I got a good code to show the div after submitting the code, but for this code work, I need to use `return false` so the page doesn't reload.

Here is the code:

```js
function showHide() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" class="generator-form" onsubmit="showHide();  return false">
            <label for="name">
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Insira seu nome" required>
            </label>
  <input type="submit" value="go">
  
  <div id="hidden">hello</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PS:** I don't know why the js is not working in here, [in codepen it's](https://codepen.io/biibis/pen/BWxzJa).

So, here's the thing:

1. I can't use `return: false` because I do need to return these values; and
2. I don't want to use `onclick()` because when the user clicks on the
   button it'll show a blank box.

To explain better, I'll get the infos I got in the form and show them in the previously hidden div. It's a signature generator for email.

There's someway I can do this with javascript or php?

Comment: where is your php code

Comment: is in the hidden div, I'm mostly using it to handle the form, but I'm thinking php maybe the best form to solve my problem since javascript didn't gave me a solution yet

Comment: your php code will be in same file na?

Comment: yes, in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$show ="none";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$show = "block";
}

?>
<html>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" class="generator-form" onsubmit="showHide();  return false">
            <label for="name">
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Insira seu nome" required>
            </label>
  <input type="submit" value="go">

  <div style="display:<?php echo $show;?>">hello</div>

</body>

</html>
```